# How to deploy a branch to Test ADF instead of Master?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Dev->Test->Prod Azure DevOps pipeline for Azure Data Factory.
I develop in "ABC" branch in dev and then I pull to master.
Finally I publish and deploy to test and then prod.

However this way I cannot test only certain features in test environment.
I get not ready features deployed to prod if my team mate deploy test to prod in middle of my testing.

Is is possible that I can deploy "ABC" branch to Test ADF instead of Master?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a clone of your CI/CD pipeline, change the artifacts branch to ABC branch, then create a variable group having ADF Name as Test ADF name and refer it in CD pipeline

This way you can always have a test pipeline available whenever you need to test your changes, I do it this way instead of messing up with main CI/CD pipeline